# JAVA_HOME error on gradle assemble release on windows

Tags: java, react-native, expo

My JAVA_HOME is set to correct path but when I run gradle assemble it says

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_
181\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

when I use java -version it gives me the correct version. what am I doing wrong here.
I am new to it so seeking help badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_
181"` there is an extra `bin`. export the new `JAVA_HOME` and try again!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is still not working. Same error now my JAVA_HOME is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`